# JPA - Select ManyToMany field

Tags: java, jpa

I have the following entity :

```
@Entity
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Seat extends AbstractEntity<Long> {
    @ManyToOne
    private Performance performance;

    @ManyToMany
    private List<Rate> availableRates;
}
```

I would like to perform the following query in JPQL :

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.availableRates FROM Seat s WHERE :performance = s.performance
```

but I keep having error as below

> could not prepare statement; SQL [select count(distinct .) as col_0_0_ from seat seat0_, seat_available_rates availabler1_, rate rate2_ where seat0_.identifier=availabler1_.seat_identifier and availabler1_.available_rates_identifier=rate2_.identifier and ?=seat0_.performance_identifier]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement

How can I write a proper query?

Comment: cant select multiple valued fields, as per the JPA spec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT r FROM Seat s JOIN s.availableRates r WHERE s.performance = :performance
```

Comment: This is it ! So my issue is not JPQL but SQL itself :) Let's go back to my books, thanks a lot